# Is it possible to pass blade directive like @if into a string from laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is the code i have tried in controller

```
$categories = Category::where('categories.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $category_name . '%')
                ->where('categories.category_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $category_code . '%')->get();
            $category_data = $categories->count();
            if ($category_data > 0) {
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $output .=
                        '<tr>
                <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
                <td><img src="' . asset($category->photo) . '" class="img-fluid" style="width: 170px; object-fit: cover;"></td>
                <td>' . $category->name . '</td>
                <td>' . $category->category_code . '</td>
                <td><a href="' . route("category.edit", $category->id) . '" class="btn btn-warning">
                                        <i class="icofont-ui-settings icofont-1x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    @if($delete == "yes")
                                    <form action="' . route("category.destroy", $category->id) . '" method="POST" class="d-inline-block" onsubmit="return confirm("Are you sure to delete the item?")">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method("DELETE")
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit"><i class="icofont-close icofont-1x"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                </tr>';
                }
                return Response($output);
```

Code in blade file, jquery

```
$('#filtersearch').click(function() {
        var category_name = $('#category_name').val();
        var category_code = $('#category_code').val();
        // alert(category_name)
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        $.get('/categorysearch', {
                category_name: category_name,
                category_code: category_code
            },
            function(data) {
                $('#filter_data').html(data);
            })
    })
```

the output looks like this[all of the blade directive are showing as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX3ec.png)

Is there a way to develop this, any solution would be very greatful.
Thanks!

Comment: not a laravel guy, but it seems the `@if` is templating system macro, so maybe if you go to the theme and locate where is this part displayed and omit the escaping or some other way to invoke templating system that would solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Concatenation in laravel for parsing string:

```
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $output .=
                    '<tr>
    <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
    <td><img src="' . asset($category->photo) . '" class="img-fluid" style="width: 170px; object-fit: cover;"></td>
    <td>' . $category->name . '</td>
    <td>' . $category->category_code . '</td>
    <td><a href="' . route("category.edit", $category->id) . '" class="btn btn-warning">
        <i class="icofont-ui-settings icofont-1x"></i>
        </a>';
        if($delete == "yes"){
            $output .= '<form action="' . route("category.destroy", $category->id) . '" method="POST" class="d-inline-block" onsubmit="return confirm("Are you sure to delete the item?")">';
            $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">';
            $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit"><i class="icofont-close icofont-1x"></i></button>
        </form>';
        }
                $output .='</td></tr>';
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is by using `render()` method
you can create your view file and pass your data and render the final HTML code

Example

```
$renderedHtml = view('your_view_file',compact('some_data'))->render();
```

then you can respond with your rendered HTML

```
return Response($renderedHtml );
```

I hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Starting from laravel 9.0, you can render blade strings on the fly

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

//...

$categories = Category::where('categories.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $category_name . '%')
                ->where('categories.category_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $category_code . '%')->get();
            $category_data = $categories->count();
            if ($category_data > 0) {
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $output .=
                        '<tr>
                <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
                <td><img src="' . asset($category->photo) . '" class="img-fluid" style="width: 170px; object-fit: cover;"></td>
                <td>' . $category->name . '</td>
                <td>' . $category->category_code . '</td>
                <td><a href="' . route("category.edit", $category->id) . '" class="btn btn-warning">
                                        <i class="icofont-ui-settings icofont-1x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    @if($delete == "yes")
                                    <form action="' . route("category.destroy", $category->id) . '" method="POST" class="d-inline-block" onsubmit="return confirm("Are you sure to delete the item?")">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method("DELETE")
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit"><i class="icofont-close icofont-1x"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                </tr>';
                }

return Blade::render($output, ['delete' => 'yes']);
```

If you're on laravel 8.x or lower, you can use this package [felixdorn/laravel-render-blade-string](https://github.com/felixdorn/laravel-render-blade-string) or the other answers solutions